# How do javascript async callbacks reference arguments that are passed in?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

With the code below, I'd expect that the timeout prints out a value of 4, since the reassignment of the variable `a` occurs before the timeout is triggered. However, 2 is printed - I'm wondering why that is the case. Does the queue for async functions make a copy of the input variables?

```
const asyncFn = (value) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(value)
    }, 500) 
}

let a = 2
asyncFn(a)
a = 4
```

Comment: Keyword: *closure*.

Comment: Parameters are passed by value, not reference. The parameter has the value 2 because a *copy* of the source value was made when the function was called.

Comment: Nothing to do with async. JS is simply a pass-by-value language, not pass-by-reference.

Comment: @mistrbrown - don't know if you missed it or not, but jonrsharpe's comment about the _closure_ is **more important** than _pass by value_. If you remove the function and call `setTimeout()` directly, you will see the result you expected. Run this in the console to see the difference: `let a = 2; setTimeout(()=>{console.log(a)}, 500); a = 4;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. I think though for you to get a better grasp of the dynamic behind this you should try the following version:

```js
const asyncFn = (obj) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(obj.value)
    }, 500) 
}

const a = { value: 2 }
asyncFn(a)
a.value = 4
```

Your example was misleading because JS passes primitive values like numbers by value and not by reference on the other hand arrays and objects are passed by reference. As you can see when you use an object we actually get the changed value in the console log!